# How to limit a border in CSS towards an image?

Tags: html, css, background

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.title {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.desc {
    padding-top: 7px;
}

.images {
    padding-left: 580px;
}

.images img {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.images img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header_inner {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Nightmare</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon.jpg">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header_inner">
                <img class="banner" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/09/12/07/58/banner-6617550__340.png">
                <div class="images">
                    <img class="icon" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604085572504-a392ddf0d86a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8b3JhbmdlJTIwZmxvd2VyfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80">
                    <p class="desc"><span class="title">Test</span><br>Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

How to change border size to the border size of an image and the footer part of an image, because the border size is not the current size of the image, and I do not know how to fix it. How can I do that?

Comment: Please could you describe in more detail what is required? Perhaps a diagram of the desired result and a diagram of what you get now.

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this?
you can just apply border for your image.
if you want to put something between border and image you can give a padding to image
or position relative and absolute to something you want to put inside them.
i hope i got your problem right.

```css
.img {
border: 5px solid black
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Nightmare</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon.jpg">
    </head>

    <body>
     <img class="img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/453426250a239cbb367afe61dca91a68?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.header_inner {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

do

```
.banner {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```